# Atajos de teclado para Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, atajo

Viendo lo importantes que pueden ser los atajos de teclado en la programación a la hora de ahorrar tiempo. Me gustaría hacer una lista de atajos para Android Studio junto con vuestra colaboración. Creo que esto ayudaría a mucha gente aprender otros atajos de teclado a parte de los que ya sabe.

La forma sería la siguiente, vosotros vais comentando en el post y yo voy editando este primer comentario o directamente vosotros vais editando este post.

La manera de simular botones en StackOverflow es la siguiente:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> Este botón se haría escribiendo lo siguiente: `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`

Lo ideal para ir dando los atajos de teclado sería la siguiente manera:

EJEMPLO:

---

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> = Buscar en todo (comandos, ficheros, menús, métodos, etc.)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> = Buscar texto en un archivo.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> =  Buscar en todos los ficheros.

---

Comment: esto no es foro para eso.
link atajos: http://androcode.es/2014/10/mejores-atajos-android-studio/

Comment: (Cntrl + F) Buscar // (Cntrl + Shift + F) Buscar en todos los ficheros

Comment: Bueno pues si no es el sitio lo cierro el post, no hay problema.

Comment: El aporte luce muy bueno y tiene buenas intenciones. Lastimosamente, el sitio no está pensado para esto.

Comment: Amigo @borjis los shortcuts estan descritos en la documentación: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html Saludos!